# Trouble connecting my raspberry pi to to Arduino Mega 2650

Tags: arduino

All -

I have followed these instructions:

http://www.mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-spi/

However when I get to the last step

```
sudo ./spidev_test
```

I never see "HELLO WORLD" in my Serial Monitor console even though my baud rate is 115200.

I did try to run the following command

```
ls -al /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/spi/
```

and it only has two kernel drivers:

- spi-bcm2708.ko
- spidev.ko

Could this be the problem ? According to the website I should have two more:

- spi-bitbang.ko
- spi-gpio.ko

How would I get a copy of these two drivers it is the problem?

When I run the "spidev_test" program I get some output that says something about "8 bits per word", but no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was indeed connecting to the wrong pins. On the 2560 the SPI pins are 50,51,52

Answer (score 0):

Using bitbang serial port is not great on Pi.

Better disable the console taking up a real UART port on the GPIO and use that instead, as described and explained in [this post.](http://baldwisdom.com/preparing-for-a-la-mode-raspberry-pi-and-arduino/)

A great add-on card  from [wyolum](http://wyolum.com/shop/25-alamode.html) will be available soon. I was lucky enough to pre-order to test with my Rev1 Pi's - Can't wait to get it.

[image]

Comment: Hi ppumpkin - Thanks for the post, but I currently need to work with what I have.  I'm starting to think this might be the problem: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10892

If you look at the link above, the SPI pins for an Arduino 2560 board are 50,51,52,53 not 10,11,12,13 (which are for Arduino UNO).  I"m going to try this out and report back to you all.